# Dreamweaver and Excel

Tags: html, excel, google-chrome, dreamweaver, frames

I imported some Excel files with frames in Dreamweaver.

In IE the frames work well, but it doesn't work in Chrome

Here's the [site](http://www.abc-camera.com/leyucca/proprio/banque.htm)

Comment: So *that's* what Dreamweaver source looks like... Ouch.

Comment: looks more like excel HTML **<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 10">**

Comment: yup. That's Excel generated code. Notice the excessive amount of classes and `mso` tags

Answer (score 1):

That looks very much like Excel generated "HTML" rather than anything Dreamweaver put out.

The basic problem is that it is covered in proprietary Microsoft gubbins which isn't supported outside of IE.

The solution is to build a proper webpage out of the data and to not trust Excel's HTML export.